# ¿Cómo generar archivos .csv con acentos en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, linux, windows, csv

Estoy haciendo un archivo .csv y se descarga bien en mi equipo (deepin)
pero al probarlo en windows no me toma los acentos, ni la ñ. Ya probé de muchas formas pero no resultan, así es mi código:

```
$callback = function()
{
    $FH = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($FH, [
        'á',
        'ñ',
    ],';','"');
    fclose($FH);
};
return Response::stream($callback, 200, [
    'charset'             => 'utf-8',
    'Content-type'        => 'text/csv;charset=utf8',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="prueba.csv"',
]);
```

Es muy simple, sin base de datos. No sé porque en deepin si funciona bien y en Windows se daña, les agradezco si me pueden guiar a la solución de este problema.

Comment: Es posible que estés generando correctamente el fichero CSV, pero sea el programa visualizador de CSV el que no está identificando correctamente la codificación del fichero. Para dar una "pista" al programa para que abra el CSV en UTF-8, puedes añadirle el BOM al fichero (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes). Estos son 3 bytes que se añaden al principio del fichero y ayudan a determinar que el fichero está en UTF-8. En este enlace puedes ver como implementarlo en php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686191/adding-bom-to-csv-file-using-fputcsv

Comment: No conocía el BOM, gracias por mencionarlo, estuve leyendo sobre el pero después de intentarlo de varias formas sigue con el mismo resultado, pero agradezco tu comentario, aprendí algo nuevo.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner una captura de pantalla del fichero abierto con un editor hexadecimal y otra captura con el fichero abierto con el visor de CSV que utilices? Así vemos si es un problema del fichero o del visualizador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo tuve el mismo problema hace dias puse esto, espero y te sirva

```
   `$fileName = 'Nombre del archivo.csv';

     $headers = array(
         "Content-Encoding"        => "utf-8",
         "Content-type"        => "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
         "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=$fileName",
         "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
         "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
         "Expires"             => "0"
     );`
```

primero declare el nombre del archivo y despues procedi a declarar el header
ahi va el formato utf-8 con eso reconocera la Ñ y caracteres especiales

```
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
```

Tambien es importante incorporar el 'echo' dentro de tu funcion callback